# Too many Literal Characters in c# WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, split

String value in my code is like:

`string abc = "Page1: This is my new Page1     --------     Page2: This is my new Page 2

 --------     Page3: This is my new Page3     --------     "`

I want to split it like:

Page1

This is my new Page1

Page2

This is my new Page 2

Page3

This is my new Page3

I wrote this code but it says that `There are two many Literals`

```
 string value =  "Page1: This is my new Page1     --------     Page2: This is my new Page 2     --------     Page3: This is my new Page3     --------     ";


 char[] delimiters = new char[] { '    --------     ' };

 string[] parts = value.Split(delimiters, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

 for (int i = 0; i < parts.Length; i++)
  {
     MesaageBox.Show(parts[i]);
  }

 parts = value.Split(new string[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

  for (int i = 0; i < parts.Length; i++)
   {
      MesaageBox.Show(parts[i]);
   }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your error is that line;

```
char[] delimiters = new char[] { '    --------     ' };
```

Obviusly,     `--------`     is not a single character. It is a **string**. Use `string` array instead of a `char` array like;

```
string[] delimiters = new string[] { "    --------     " };
```

Full example;

```
string value =  "Page1: This is my new Page1     --------     Page2: This is my new Page 2     --------     Page3: This is my new Page3     --------     ";
string[] delimiters = new string[] { "     --------     " };
string[] parts = value.Split(delimiters, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

foreach (var item in parts)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Output will be;

```
Page1: This is my new Page1
Page2: This is my new Page 2
Page3: This is my new Page3
```

Here a <kbd>[`demonstration`](http://ideone.com/U8LA7i)</kbd>.

If you want to output like;

```
Page1
This is my new Page1
Page2
This is my new Page 2
Page3
This is my new Page3
```

You just need to add `:` in your string array to split part. Like;

```
string[] delimiters = new string[] { "     --------     ", ":"};
```

> and how to get page1 page 2 ?

You can get them like;

```
Console.WriteLine(delimiters[0]); //Prints Page1
Console.WriteLine(delimiters[2]); //Prints Page2
```

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Ups missed that. Thanks. Updated.

Comment: and how to get page1 page 2 ?

Comment: @user2835256 Updated in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you need to use the `string[]` overload:

```
string[] delimiters = new string[] { "    --------     " };
```

A `char` is defined as a single character. So, when you do this `'    --------     '` it can't build that. That's not a `char`, that's a `string`. And quite frankly, that's what you're looking for.

So, by changing it from a `char[]` to a `string[]` you'll use the right overload.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record.  Here is another option using a regular expression:

```
string value =  "Page1: This is my new Page1     --------     Page2: This is my new Page 2     --------     Page3: This is my new Page3     --------     ";
string[] delimiters = new string[] { "     --------     " };
string[] parts = Regex.Split(value, @"(?<=Page\d+): |\s+-{8}\s+");

foreach (var item in parts)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```